# Get a reference to search product results based on attribute within catalog/layer/view.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I am trying to get the search product results based on attribute filter in catalog/layer/view.phtml

suppose my query like this, if my attribute filter is "length" then,

SELECT * FROM catalog_products WHERE searchstring LIKE 's%' and attribute_filter='length';
how can i get this result in magento.

Comment: First and for most thing is that if you using custom query with the magento is not a good programming style. Please , Try to use Catalog/Products collection. and use AddAttributetoFilter. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can i write Catalog/Products collection using AddAttributetoFilter. i have tried many ways using AddAttributetoFilter but it is not working. Please guide me